# Run .NET Core on IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I tried to set up IIS on my local machine to run .NET Core API. I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis article. I published code (using dotnet publish) to temp folder and on IIS set up to use this temp folder.

I'm getting HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure error in browser.

In event logs there is an error:

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/DEFAULT WEB SITE' with physical root 
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\' failed to start process with
>   commandline '"" ', ErrorCode = '0x80070057 : 0.

I upgraded .NET Core from 1.0 to 1.1, created new application pool (.NET CLR Version No Mananged Code), installed all required updates, web.config is created and looks good, but still doesn't work.
I found some posts here but they didn't help for me.

Does anyone have same issue?

Comment: I got same issue... Really fustrating ...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have "Microsoft.AspNetCore.IISIntegration.Tools" in project.json under the tools section?

It should be like this;

```
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
```

Maybe another problem in web.config framewokr can not find dotnet.exe;
Try this in web.config;

```
<aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments=".\YourNetCoreProject.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
```

instead of LAUNCHER_PATH and LAUNCHER_ARGS

Comment: Yes, I have "Microsoft.AspNetCore.IISIntegration.Tools".

Comment: is it under "tools" section like I wrote in my post?

Comment: Yes, it is. Tools section is correct in project.json

Comment: I edited my post for another thing maybe it is a web.config error. Pls try hard coded path of dotnet.exe and your project dll path

Comment: dotnet publish replaces processPath and arguments. I tried to hardcode full path (C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe) but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Algirdas have you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The error reads

> with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\'

You said the site was published to a temp folder, e.g. c:\temp. The default site should be then configured to use physical path c:\temp instead of C:\inetpub\wwwroot\