# .NET Core app runs locally on web server, but not accessible via remote browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.1 web app which I've published to a remote server.

I've set the website up in IIS following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore1x). I know the bindings and firewall etc are configured right because before I installed the .NET Core app I could browse to the binding URL and see the IIS default page.

After adding the .NET Core application to the website directory, browsing to the same URL just returns a **HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure** error. However, if I run the application in a command prompt locally on the server (running `dotnet .\MyProject.dll`) it reports that the application started OK. At this point I can browse to the site locally on http://localhost:5000 and it works correctly.

So I assume this is an issue with my IIS setup. What might I have missed? I've installed the [ASP.NET Core 1.1.1 Hosting Package](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=844461). The application pool user has modify permission on my application directory and read permission on C:\program files\dotnet. The app pool is configured for no managed code. Clearly the runtime is correctly installed or it wouldn't work locally. Unfortunately the server's event viewer is not very helpful, just gives me:

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MYPROJECT' with physical root
>   'C:\Sites\MyProject\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet
>   .\MyProject.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80070002 : 0

Any assistance would be very appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

I hadn't long posted this when I found [this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444723/run-net-core-on-iis). One of the unaccepted answers suggested changing "dotnet" to "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" in the web.config to end up with this:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments=".\Picsolve.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
```

This fixed the problem! Can anyone explain why this ight have been? I've checked my system environment variables and can see C:\Program Files\dotnet in there.

Comment: Error code 0x80070002 means "file not found", maybe this will help.

Comment: When you deploy out, your file structure won't necessarily be rooted at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe". you need to make use of a relative path

Comment: Post what you learnt as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I would suspect that this is entirely on purpose. The system PATH environmental variable is a security threat vector that people have been hacking since it existed. It is generally considered best practice to force people to use the full path to an executable rather than finding it in the path. Just imagine if someone managed to install a C:\reallyevildotnet\bin in your path before "C:\program files\dotnet".

Comment: It might also be possible that if you restart IIS it discovers a newly updated PATH variable and "dotnet" works just fine.