# How should I configure publishing to ensure ASP.NET Core uses the correct process path

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core (v1.1) web application. The web.config has the following line:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
```

I understand this is used by my local IIS Express to start up the application locally.

I'm now configuring publishing as part of an automated deployment to a remote server. After publishing, the web.config has been changed to this:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyProject.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
```

When deployed to the remote server this errors. I found that changing the `processPath` to the full executable path (C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe) fixed the problem. Responses to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735897/net-core-app-runs-locally-on-web-server-but-not-accessible-via-remote-browser) suggest this might be a deliberate security feature to prevent hackers targeting the system PATH variable. I tried just changing the web.config in the source to set that path explicitly, but unfortunately every time I run the site locally the value gets changed back to `%LAUNCHER_PATH%`.

So my question is, how can I ensure my published application contains the correct process path? Or perhaps the correct question is: what should I configure on the deployment web server to ensure it can use the system PATH variable?

Answer (score 1):

The Web.config isn't something you should be editing or even need to be concerned about with an ASP.NET Core app. It's only there because IIS needs it, simply to start the app. In that regard, however it's published should be perfectly fine.

If `dotnet.exe` isn't on the system PATH, then there was likely some issue with the installation of the runtime, since this should happen automatically. You can either reinstall the runtime or simply add the `C:\Program Files\dotnet` portion to your system `PATH` environment variable manually.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but `C:\Program Files\dotnet` is already in the system `PATH` variable. Hence my final question: "what should I configure on the deployment web server to ensure it can use the system PATH variable". Could this be a permissions thing? My appliction pool user does have read/execute permission on `C:\Program Files\dotnet`...

Comment: This really has nothing to do with .NET Core or IIS. The `PATH` environment variable is a Windows thing. It simply makes executables in directories reference there available on the command line without having to prefix a full path to them. If that's not working, first, ensure that the `PATH` variable is set in the system environment variables, not the user environment variables. Second, you might try restarting the machine, to get Windows to pick up the environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried all that. But you're right, if this is the problem then it's not a question for SO. I've asked a question on Server Fault and will report back if I get an answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/879977/why-isnt-iis-on-windows-server-2012-able-to-access-system-environment-variables

Comment: Confirmed over on Server Fault, this is a security measure. Solution is to remove web.config from deployment mechanism and ensure deployment servers have a web.config with full path configured to ensure ASP.NET starts up correctly. (ref: https://serverfault.com/questions/879977/why-isnt-iis-on-windows-server-2012-able-to-access-system-environment-variables)